# "Kinda figured it out " vs "kinda figured out"

Tags: expressions, speech

Example:

> **Speaker A:** Were you surprised about my confession?
>
> **Speaker B:** Not really. Kinda figured (it) out when you held my hand last night."

*Kinda figured it out* has [180](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1280&bih=938&tbm=bks&q=%22kinda%20figured%20it%20out%20%22&oq=%22kinda%20figured%20it%20out%20%22&gs_l=serp.3...49252.49426.0.49519.3.3.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.msedr...0...1c.1.64.serp..3.0.0.GxW_ky73xeA) hits on Google Books. *Kinda figured out has* [394](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1280&bih=938&tbm=bks&q=%22kinda%20figured%20out%20%22&oq=%22kinda%20figured%20out%20%22&gs_l=serp.3...1696.1696.0.1776.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.msedr...0...1c.1.64.serp..1.0.0.Mz2gWSZVZBY) hits on Google Books. So I'm not sure which one is more idiomatic and common in informal speech.

Comment: The hits for _kinda figured out_ were probably followed by an object:  _kinda figured out [X]_  or   _kinda figured out [how to X]_ or   _kinda figured out [why X did Y]_  In your example,  _kinda figured **it** out_ is apt.

Comment: Jason Chen meet jano Chen. . .

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ha, and I think we look alike.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the data comparison looks flawed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two phrases "kinda figured it out" and "kinda figured out" can both be grammatically correct (assuming you use colloquial language instead of "kind of"), but they must be used in different contexts.

"Kinda figured it out" can be used like a verb:

> I kinda figured it out.

while "kinda figured out" can be used like an adjective:

> I got it kinda figured out.

So it depends on which one you prefer.